# EXTJS 4.2 - messageProperty, successProperty, totalProperty

Tags: php, extjs

In EXTJS 4.2 , for `Ext.data.reader.Reader` there is `messageProperty, successProperty, totalProperty` configuration to set.

My question is if I don't set these config in reader then also i can fetch the same in my store load event (I i have send something from server).

*EXT JS Code:*

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '...',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
        },
```

*PHP server response*

```
array('message' => 'No data found');
```

*on EXT JS*

```
store.load: function(store, records, options){

               console.log(store.getProxy().getReader().rawData);
            },
```

Then what is use of  `messageProperty, successProperty, totalProperty` configuration, If without setting them also I can fetch server data.
May be I am not aware of how to use it ...please guide me

Answer (score 1):

[messsageProperty](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-messageProperty) , [successProperty](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-successProperty) , [totalProperty](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-totalProperty) are for different purpose.
If you specify them, you can access them like **getMessage**, **getSuccess**, **getTotal** from reader

Comment: when I write `console.log(this.getStore().getProxy().getReader().getMessage());` on store load...It says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gridMessage' of undefined ` where `gridMessage` is defined in reader `messageProperty:'gridMessage'`

Comment: Can you give me a example of what you are trying to do. May be http://jsfiddle.net/ will help me in solving it easily

Answer (score 1):

Well you are getting it wrong. Basically purpose/use of those properties is :

1) `totalProperty` : When you apply paging, this property will come into the scenario. Total number of records available will be specified using this property. Consider the example, there are 100 accounts, and you are showing them 10 at a time in a grid. And your response is like `{totalAccounts: 100, data : {account1, account2, ..., account10}}`. Here, paging will create 10 pages using `number_of_pages=totalAccounts/10`. Here, in reader, at the time of configuring reader, you will specify this property like:

```
reader: {           
    root: 'data',
    type: 'json',
    totalProperty: 'totalAccounts'
}
```

2) `successProperty`: Sometimes, you may want to know whether your request is successful or failed? In this case, this parameter can be customized. You can set success parameter what server is returning. For e.g. I use requestStatus as `successProperty` as server returns whether current request is processed successfully or it has errors.

3) `messageProperty`: similar to `successProperty`, but here you can use messages from server side directly.